# "Command returned non-zero exit code" when trying to set M2 to production mode

Tags: magento2

When I try to `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` I get the error

> Command returned non-zero exit code

I already tried to

- increase memory with `-d memory_limit=2G`
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- clear `var/cache`

nothing worked.

When I do

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation

bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

it runs successfully but the frontpage is messed up. The standard Luna theme is just a HTML output without any CSS or JS.

Here's the output of

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -vvv
```

> #0 /vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Filesystem.php(267):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Shell->execute('/opt/plesk/php/...')
>       #1 /vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Filesystem.php(172): Magento\Deploy\Model\Filesystem->compile(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>       #2 /vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Mode.php(139): Magento\Deploy\Model\Filesystem->regenerateStatic(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>       #3 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Model\Mode->Magento\Deploy\Model{closure}()
>       #4 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Console/MaintenanceModeEnabler.php(85):
>   call_user_func(Object(Closure))
>       #5 /vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Mode.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\Console\MaintenanceModeEnabler->executeInMaintenanceMode(Object(Closure),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), false)
>       #6 /vendor/magento/module-deploy/Console/Command/SetModeCommand.php(101):
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Mode->enableProductionMode()
>       #7 /vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\SetModeCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>       #8 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(893): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>       #9 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(262): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\SetModeCommand),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>       #10 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(102): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>       #11 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(145): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is the compilation successful?

Comment: Yes, it says "Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully". (but only if I do --skip-compilation and then setup:di:compile). But then the page is messed up, though.

Comment: Give read and write permission to "generated", "Var", "app/etc"  and "pub/static" folder.

Comment: Hm, these folders already have read/write permission.

Comment: Can you please check your log files? Can you deploy the files once again in production mode? Are you getting any 404 errors in your browser console?

Comment: I deployed the files again and now getting "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.". Which log files should I check? Thanks

Comment: Check your magento_root/var/log/exception.log file

Comment: This file does not exists unfortunatelly.

Comment: So don't you find debug.log, system.log files there? If else please check in your server log file for any errors.

Comment: Sounds like it's the setup:static-content:deploy step that is failing. Try running with -vvv and see if you get a more helpful stack trace. If so maybe post it here.

Comment: In the debug.log I get errors like:

[2019-04-01 08:43:09] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}} []
[2019-04-01 08:43:23] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_design_config_grid_flat_1"}} []
[2019-04-01 08:43:23] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_design_config_grid_flat_2"}} []

Comment: In system.log there is this: Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 66.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 589824 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/xxx/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Comment: Can you increase php memory_limit value?

Comment: I tried to run it with  php -d memory_limit=2G  bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
and I also increased the memory limit to 2G in Plesk.

Comment: Can you confirm the PHP value increased by creating a php info file containing phpinfo() command in your magento root

Comment: Yes, it says: memory_limit 756M (local value) 2048M (master value)

Comment: Try setting local value to 2gb as if master value

Comment: Have solved this erroe ?

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Finally solved by changing the PHP memory_limit to 5G

Answer (score 1):

> php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

Won't work to solve this problem.

To fix this you need to increase the **PHP Memory Limit** in the ***php.ini*** file on your server.

Increase it to any greater value e.g **1024M or 2G or 5G.**

This will solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should press command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command:

```
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```

Please let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

hi your problem is solved i have the same problem do help me please

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when switching to production mode from developer mode.

[image]

To fix it I ran following commands to give proper permissions to files and directories.

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

After this is issue is fexed.